# Master Theorem with constant

Tags: algorithm, master-theorem

Is this Formula a case 2 from the Master Theorem

```
T(n) = 2 * T(n/2) + 3
```

`a = 2; b = 2; (f(n) = 3^1) ?`

so logba = 1 and c = 1 in this case is it master theorem case 2 ? 
or should i ignore the constant 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [case 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_1) formula, since:

```
log_b(a) = 1
f(n) = 3,
3 is in O(1)=O(n^0) -> c = 0 < 1 = log_b(a)
```

So, the formula is in `Theta(n^(log_b(a)) = Theta(n)`

This is NOT case 2, because case 2 requires `f(n)=3` to be in `Theta(n^(log_b(a)) = Theta(n)`, but `f(n)=3` is NOT in `Theta(n)`